# Naturality of Conditional Expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, category-theory, conditional-expectation, functors

---

**Context**

Let $\mathscr{G}$ be a $\sigma$-subalgebra of $\mathscr{F}$ and let $\mathbb{P}$ be a probability measure on a polish-space $X$.

Define the category $\mathfrak{C}$ of random-elements in $L^1(\mathbb{P};\mathscr{G})$ with arrows continuous maps of $X$ onto itself.  Similarly, define the category $\mathfrak{D}$ of random-elements in $L^1(\mathbb{P};\mathscr{F})$ with arrows continuous maps of $X$ onto itself.

The conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}}\left[\cdot|\mathscr{G}\right]$ maps the objects of $\mathfrak{D}$ to those of $\mathfrak{C}$ and the precomposition map $\phi_{\star}$ defined by
$$
\phi \rightarrow \mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}}\left[\phi(\cdot)|\mathscr{G}\right]
.
$$ Defines a map from $\mathfrak{D}$ to $\mathfrak{C}$.  This makes conditional expectation into a functor

---

**Question**

Is there a way to canonical way of associating to every $\xi,\eta \in L^1(\mathbb{P};\mathscr{F})$, and every continuous map $\phi$ from $X$ to itself such that
$$
\eta = \phi(\xi)
$$
to a density $Z^{\phi} \in L^1(\mathbb{P};\mathscr{F})$ such that
$$
\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}}\left[\eta|\mathscr{G}\right]=
\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}}\left[Z^{\phi}\xi|\mathscr{G}\right]
.
$$